# Facebook Like Button Count for URLS that Already Have Likes/Shares/Comments

Tags: facebook-like

I am trying to implement a like button on a blog. The blog gets a decent amount of traffic and most posts get 10-30 likes, 5-10 shares and any number of comments on Facebook. I am implementing a like button for each post using the iFrame code copied straight from Facebook's Like Button page (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). When I do test URLS, like "test.com" a count will show up; however, when I use a URL from the site that I know has a combination of shares/likes/comments, no count shows. Additionally, when I run the link through the graph.facebook.com, it shows that there are shares (e.g., http://graph.facebook.com/http://test.com). Now, if I pressed the like button I do get a count of "1" to show up. My questions are thus:

1) Should I expect the count to show up for posts that have shares/likes/comments, but I'm just now implementing the button for it?

2) Is there anything special that needs to be done with the URL sent? URL encoding? Adding/not adding "http://"?

3) Is there a latency to the count? For instance are the counts cached and updated at different times?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I don't think they will ever show up if they haven't so far.. (see answer 3)

2) No. An URL with or without http:// will be treated as the same URL. But I recommend using http://

3) If by latency you mean delay, then no. Likes/shares/comments count are updated almost instantly.